# How do I get all words before and after a character?

Tags: ruby, regex

I never tried regex before today, and I like it so far, but I'm lost on some things.

I have a string that looks like this:

```
Type OtherType ThirdType - SubType AnotherSubType QuiteTheType
```

I want two regex, both care about the '`-`' character.
First I want all words before that character, then all words after it.  I will be using Ruby's `gsub` to turn them into an array of strings, two arrays, which is why I need two regex expressions.

So far I have this: `([a-zA-z]{1,}) (?=-)` but that only gets me the word right before the dash, I.E. `ThirdType`. 
If I just use `([a-zA-z]{1,})` I get all words highlighted, but that includes the ones AFTER the `-` which I don't want yet.

How can I get all occurrences of `[a-zA-z]{1,}` that happen before `-` but not necessarily IMMEDIATELY before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how Ruby's regex implementation works, but the following regex in Perl should get you what you want:

```
/^([a-zA-z\s]+) \- ([a-zA-Z\s]+)$/
```

For example:

```
perl -e '$_="Type OtherType ThirdType - SubType AnotherSubType QuiteTheType";
if(/^([a-zA-z\s]+) \- ([a-zA-Z\s]+)$/){print "$1\n";print "$2\n";}'
```

produces

```
Type OtherType ThirdType
SubType AnotherSubType QuiteTheType
```

ETA:  To explain what's going on, the initial `^` denotes the beginning of the line and the ending `$` denotes the end of the line.  So, `^([a-zA-Z\s]+)` starts at the beginning and (greedily) matches all of the words from the beginning of the line up until the space before the dash (which is escaped by a backslash, since `-` is a reserved character in most regex implementations).  Likewise with `([a-zA-Z\s]+)$`.

Comment: I'm using gskinner.com's Regex tool and yours doesn't pick anything up.  Not sure why.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you tried eliminating the beginning and end slashes from the regex, ie just entering `^([a-zA-z\s]+) \- ([a-zA-Z\s]+)$`?  It's possible that the regex tool doesn't use them and instead looks for literal slashes in the string (which, of course, wouldn't match).

Comment: It automatically removes them actually, even if I type them in.  Weird.  Guess it doesn't like the perl Regex engine.

Comment: If I remove `^` and `$` it nearly works on the first part, except it gives me the dash as part of the last item, but I want it without the dash.  Still, I like that you explained it!

Comment: Hmmm, googling "ruby regex", I found the Rubular Ruby regex editor, and it seems to work there:  http://www.rubular.com/r/9u7HYB5dOX  I'm honestly not 100% sure what to tell you.

Comment: AHA! Changed it from `\-` to `(?=\-)` and I get what I want!  Thanks!  Picking your answer for the simple fact that you explained it.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad  you got it to work!  And you're most welcome.

Comment: So what I came up with (for the "before") is `([a-zA-z\s]+) (?=\-)`.  Haven't figured out the "after" which needs to be a separate RegEx anyway.

Comment: If you know the general form of your string, you can also split the string on the substring " - ".  See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "Type OtherType ThirdType - SubType AnotherSubType QuiteTheType"

words_before, words_after = s.split(/\s*-\s*/).map do |t|
  t.split(/\s+/)
end
p words_before    # => ["Type", "OtherType", "ThirdType"]
p words_after     # => ["SubType", "AnotherSubType", "QuiteTheType"]
```

Here's how this works:

```
s.split(/\s*-\s*/)
```

This splits the string in two, using a regular expression delimiter.  The delimiter means "any amount of white-space, then a dash, then any amount of white-space."  The result is an array with two strings in it: The part on the left of the delimeter, and the part on the right.

```
...map do |t|
  ...
end
```

map takes an array and transforms it into another array with the same number of elements.  It takes each element of the array, passes it to the block, and uses the return value from the block as the new value for that element.  We'll use it to transform the two strings into two arrays of words.

So, what's in the block?

```
t.split(/\s+/)
```

It's another split.  This time we'll split on one or more whitespace characters.  That results in an array of words.

Since the map applies that split to first the left side and then the right side, the result of the entire `s.split...` expression is an array of two arrays.

Now we'll use one of Ruby's fun syntaxes:

```
words_before, words_after = s.split...
```

Whenever you have multiple variables on the left side of an assignment, ruby will "decompose" the array on the right side, assigning the first element of the array to the first variable, the second element of the array to the second variable, and so on.  Since our array has two elements (the first being an array of words from the left side, and the second being an array of words from the right side), we'll use two variables to hold them.

Comment: I like this answer too, but please, explain it.  It doesn't help anyone for you to give me something to paste, I want to LEARN and know WHY it works.

Comment: @James, Well said, and fair enough.  I've added an explanation.  If it's lacking, please let me know where and I'll attempt to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use look-ahead:

`(\w+)(?=.*?-)`

Comment: Mind explaining this?  I see that it does what I want...but why?  I thought that `(?=-)` was already doing a look-ahead.

Comment: You are correct, `(?=-)` is doing a look-ahead, but it does not skip anything, therefore, as per your question, only the "word right before the dash" is found.

`(\w+) (?=-)` => one or more word characters, followed by a single space, look-ahead for single dash.

`(\w+)(?=.*?-)` => one or more word characters, look-ahead for any characters, non-greedy, followed by a single dash.

Answer (score 1):

While regex is powerful and useful, it often leads to a more complicated solution than you need, and complicated results in more work and maintenance.

```
sentence = 'Type OtherType ThirdType - SubType AnotherSubType QuiteTheType'

sentence.split('-') # => ["Type OtherType ThirdType ", " SubType AnotherSubType QuiteTheType"]
sentence.scan(/[^-]+/) # => ["Type OtherType ThirdType ", " SubType AnotherSubType QuiteTheType"]
```

If the whitespace surrounding the hyphen is annoying pass the returned sections through `strip`:

```
sentence.split('-').map{ |w| w.strip } # => ["Type OtherType ThirdType", "SubType AnotherSubType QuiteTheType"]
sentence.scan(/[^-]+/).map{ |w| w.strip } # => ["Type OtherType ThirdType", "SubType AnotherSubType QuiteTheType"]
```

If you want the individual words, and not the sentences before and after the hyphen:

```
sentence.split('-').map{ |w| w.strip.split(' ') } # => [["Type", "OtherType", "ThirdType"], ["SubType", "AnotherSubType", "QuiteTheType"]]
sentence.scan(/[^-]+/).map{ |w| w.strip.split(' ') } # => [["Type", "OtherType", "ThirdType"], ["SubType", "AnotherSubType", "QuiteTheType"]]
```

Comment: Good post, but partly I want a reason to learn Regex, and also this string is actually more complex in that I will also have to find numbers that may or may not be separated by a slash like `2/2` or `4` at the end of the string.  Still, I like you answer and might adopt it.

Comment: @James P. Wright, Regular expressions are important to know, but don't consider them the answer to every parsing problem. Every experienced programer has tales of regular expressions leaking in bad ways, because the complexity got out of control. Be willing to break the problem down into several small steps, rather than try to do everything in one big pattern, and you'll side step a lot of the problems. And, like in my examples, often regex are not the most direct path so don't let them seduce you. Regular expressions belong in a toolbox but they are not necessarily the most useful tool.